# How can I convert a CSV string to HTML tags?

Tags: php, csv

Here is my string:

```
$str = "php,html,css";
```

And this is expected result:

```
$newstr = "<a href='?t=php'>php</a><a href='?t=html'>html</a><a href='?t=css'>css</a>"
```

What's the cleanest way to do that by PHP?

---

I can do that by exploding that string and make it like this:

```
$arr = explode(",", $str);
$html = '';
foreach( $arr as $tag ){
    $html .= "<a href='?t=$tag'>$tag</a>";
}
$newstr = $html;
```

But I guess that's not what a professional programmer will do.

Comment: If it works go for it. Exploding the string is the obvious way, so that's where I would have started. Or spend more time and work out the regex. Not much professional about spending more time on something simple.

Comment: I did that, and I realize that i'm not a pro. huhuu T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `str_getcsv()`, `array_map()`, `sprintf()`, and `implode()`:

```
$str = "php,html,css";

$newstr = implode('', array_map(function ($type) {
    return sprintf(
        '<a href="?t=%s">%s</a>',
        $type,
        $type
    );
}, str_getcsv($str)));
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/n3PSS

Alternatively, you could use `str_getcsv()`, `array_reduce()`, and `sprintf()`:

```
$str = "php,html,css";

$newstr = array_reduce(str_getcsv($str), function ($carry, $type) {
    return $carry . sprintf(
        '<a href="?t=%s">%s</a>',
        $type,
        $type
    );
}, '');
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/r7WIR